# Don't understand how Hurwitz's Theorem implies its corollaries

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have the following statement of Hurwitz's Theorem which I understand how to prove:

> Let G be a region and suppose the sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $H(G)$ converges to $f$. If $f\not\equiv0$, $\bar{B}(a; R)\subset G$, and $f(z)\neq0$ for $|z-a|<R$  then there is an integer $N$ such that for $n\geq N$, $f$ and $f_n$ have the same number of zeros in $B(a; R)$.

And the following corollary:

> If $\{f_n\}\subset H(G)$ converges to $f$ in $H(G)$ and each $f_n$ never vanishes on $G$ then either $f\equiv 0$ or $f$ never vanishes.

I can't understand how the theorem immediately implies the corollary? I understand that under the conditions of Hurwitz's Theorem given that $f_n$ never vanishes then $f$ never vanishes. However I can't understand what happens if $f\not\equiv0$ but $f(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0$ in $|z-a|<R$.

Comment: There is a mistake in your formulation. You should have for $|z-a|<R$ and not $|z-a|=R$. Also uniform convergence on compacta is necessary, I don't know if that is what you meant with converge.

Comment: Yeah taking convergence to be uniform on all compact sets of $G$. And edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement of the theorem is basically the following:

If $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compacta $f, f_n$ are holomorphic and $f$ is not the zero function, then inside each closed ball the number of zeros that $f$ has is eventually equal to the number of zeros of the $f_n$.

To get the corollary assume that $f$ is not the zero functions and $f_n \to f$ as in the theorem.

If the $f_n$ have no zeros, then the amount of zeros of the $f_n$ in any closed ball is always zero. But this is eventually equal to the amount of zeros of $f$ in this ball, so $f$ cannot have any zeros in this ball.

Now since $G$ is a region, it is open. This means that for any point $p$ in it we have a ball $B_t(p)\subset G$. Since $\overline {B_{t/2}(p)}\subset B_t(p)$ we also have a closed ball containing $p$. Since $f$ has no zeros in the closed ball, it is not zero at $p$. Since $p$ was arbitrary in $G$ f has no zeros at all.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now

Comment: @George1811 I have written a little more

Comment: But to apply the Hurwitz's Theorem you have to make sure that $f$ is non-vanishing on the boundary of the closed ball you chosen. But I do not see this in your proof. And I am so wonder that this condition is missed in the statement of the corollary of Hurwitz's theorem

Comment: Can I say in this way? Suppose $f$ is not zero function and there is a point $z_0$ such that $f(z_0)=0$. By identity mapping theorem, there is a small ball $B_r(z_0)$ such that $z_0$ is the only zero of $f$. So $f(z)$ is non-vanishing on $\partial B_{r/2}(z_0)$. So we would apply Hurwitz's Theorem inside $B_{r/2}(z_0)$ so that we obtain the contradiction that $f$ has a zero in $B_{r/2}(z_0)$ but $f_n(z)$ is never vanishing in $B_{r/2}(z_0)$.

Comment: The argument in the answer goes as follows: Around any point $p$ you have an open ball that is contained in $G$. Inside this open ball the $f_n$ are never zero. There is a smaller closed ball contained inside the open ball. On this closed ball (and this includes the boundary) the functions $f_n$ are not zero. Applying Hurwitz (under the assumption that $f$ is not the zero function) on this smaller closed ball retrieves that $f$ admits not zeros on the smaller closed ball. It follows $f$ is not zero at $p$, as this point lies in the closed ball. But $p$ was arbitrary.