# Uniform convergence of a sequence of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, holomorphic-functions

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions. Suppose that $f_n$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on compact subsets of $U$ and that $f$ is not identically zero in $U$ and $f(w)=0$ for some $w \in U$.

Prove that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and a sequence $\{z_n\}$ such that $f_n(z_n) = 0$ for all $n \geq N$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z_n = w$.

How can I prove the existence of $z_n$ and $f_n(z_n)$ is exactly 0? 
Any idea?

Comment: Feels like an $\epsilon/3$ argument to me.

Comment: Hint: try with [Hurwitz's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652188/dont-understand-how-hurwitzs-theorem-implies-its-corollaries).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $\Gamma$ be a circle around $w$ such that $\Gamma$ and its interior are in $U$, and $f_n$ is nonzero on $\Gamma$.  Then $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma \dfrac{f_n'(z)\; dz}{f_n(z)}$$ is the number of zeros of $f_n$ (counted by multiplicity) inside $\Gamma$